# Roblox - Infinite yield possible on 'ReplicatedStorage.bpg.packages:WaitForChild("Instance")'

Tags: module, lua, roblox, luau

I have been working on a basic Roblox script where I require every moduleScript in a folder!
I managed to snatch a code snippet from the DevForums, but it didn't work as expected.

My code is as follows:

```
21 | for _, x in pairs(packages:GetChildren()) do
22 |    packageHandler[x] = require(script.Parent.packages:WaitForChild(x))
23 |    if not packageHandler[x] and logEnabled then 
24 |          print("Could not find package "..x.."! Are you certain it exists?") 
25 |    end
26 | end
27 |
28 | return packageHandler
```

When required via. my Parent script (module script), it returns a warning on the first module script of which it tries to require:

`Infinite yield possible on 'ReplicatedStorage.bpg.packages:WaitForChild("Instance")'`

This warning occurs on line 22!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to `require(x)` as `x` is an instance and I cant use `:WaitForChild(x)` on an instance (according to LukaDev).

Answered!